# Multiprocessing in Python using Pool Class

Tags: python, serialization, python-multiprocessing, dill, pathos

I want to use multiprocessing in python(specifically Pool Class) in windows(zeppelin notebook). But after reading a lot I got to know that the Pool Class uses pickle in its back end and can be use for only the objects that can be pickled. As I can't serialize a function or a class using pickle in Python(at least in 3.6 version), I found out that pathos.multiprocessing library can be used to perform multiprocessing as it uses `dill` instead of pickle in the back end which according to `dill` package documentation can serialize anything. But when I used it I got errors. Below is the simple code that I used:

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

def cube(x):
    return x**3

p = mp.Pool(4)

p.apply(cube, [1,2,3])
```

And this is the error I got:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o0.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:279)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I got the same error even if I used map, apply_async or map_async. Can someone help me finding out the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the example you gave, the standard multiprocess library will work.  Are you trying to map something more complicated?

Comment: Hi James, You can't use standard multiprocessing library as well for doing this. When you do this using standard library you get the pickle error - `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function cube at 0x7f3283ee3048>: attribute lookup cube on __main__ failed`.

Comment: Are you trying to run in interactive mode?

Comment: Yes I am using a zeppelin notebook

Comment: @ShubhamKedia did you solve this problem by any means?

Answer (score 0):

Also If i use the code like the this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def cube(x):
    return x**3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    p.apply(cube, [1,2,3])
```

I don't see any output returned. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Read the comments, he is running in interactive mode through a Zeppelin notebook